# Javascript code and methods do not work

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning javascrpt, but I have some experience with C#. My school gave me an old text book called Complete Concepts and Techniques(second Edition). this book was written by Shelly Cashman and Dorin Quasney... My problem is that I cant get any of the methods or functions to work. Here are 2 of my most current issues:

```
  var scrollMsg = "Mortage rates are at their lowest!"
  var msgSpace = "---   ---"
  var beginPos = 0
  function scrollingMsg() {
     document.msgForm.scrollingMsg.value = 
  scrollMsg.substring(beginPos,scrollMsg.length)+msgSpace+scrollMsg.substring(0,begi
  nPos)
     beginPos = beginPos + 1
     If (beginPos > scrollMsg.length) {
         beginPos = 0
     }
    window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200)
}



 function doMort() {
    document.MortCalc.Amount.value=" "
    document.MortCalc.Rate.value=" "
    document.MortCalc.Years.value=" "
    document.MortCalc.Payment.value" "
    document.MortCalc.Amount.focus()
 }
```

The scrollingMsg() function does not work. It does not place anything in the scrollingMsg text box. So there is no message in it. My second issue is with the doMort() function. The function does clear any of the boxes nor does it set a focus. Can you please tell me what's wrong. P.S. These are not my own code. These were project codes from the txt book, but they do not work.

Comment: If that code came from the book, get a different book.

Comment: That book is an **antique**.

Comment: I can't see any reason that shouldn't work … but the techniques used are decidedly not modern. I'd recommend getting a more up to date guide.

Comment: you need semi colons and honestly W3schools looks like it could teach you better than this book

Comment: An implementation of a scrolling marquee? I'm going to vote this down just for the sake of humanity. We barely survived this sort of thing in the 1990s. People are still suffering PTSD from them.

Comment: The book is old. I would like to get another book, but I cant because the school will be testing me from this book.

Comment: Open the javascript console in whatever browser you're using, and have a look at any errors that are raised.  This will tell you why your code isn't running.  (If no errors appear, use the debugger feature to step through the code and see what's happening at each line.)

Comment: I'm using firefox. I'm not familiar with the web console and the debugger, but I opened the console. There are 3 syntax errors. I'll try to solve them then I'll comment again

Comment: I cant understand what this means : [13:31:44.409] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/KaS/My%20Documents/javascript/homefinders2.htm#LoanCalc

Answer (score 0):

Try adding semicolons after each statement, and you have a typo ('If' needs to be lowercase).

Comment: also you're missing the equals sign from document.MortCalc.Payment.value" "

Comment: I added them, but it did not make a difference

Comment: It's too long to paste

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code to comply with JSLint, use this site to verify your javascript
http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

```
var scrollMsg = "Mortage rates are at their lowest!";
var msgSpace = "---   ---";
var beginPos = 0;

    function scrollingMsg() {
         document.msgForm.scrollingMsg.value = scrollMsg.substring(beginPos,scrollMsg.length) + msgSpace + scrollMsg.substring(0,beginPos);
         beginPos = beginPos + 1;

         if (beginPos > scrollMsg.length) {
             beginPos = 0;
          }
          window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200);
     }


     function doMort() {
            document.MortCalc.Amount.value=" ";
            document.MortCalc.Rate.value=" ";
            document.MortCalc.Years.value=" ";
            document.MortCalc.Payment.value=" ";
            document.MortCalc.Amount.focus();
      }
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, but it did not make anything work. Thanks for the help though.